# Minimizing Multiple Functions

Tags: mathematical-optimization, homework

I'm trying to write a script that will minimize a given set of functions. The homework problem I've been given lists a set of dietary information, and I'm supposed to build the optimal salad based on those parameters.

What I can't figure out is how to use the data returned by the Minimize function.  The documentation for the Minimize function doesn't specify anything about it.

```
cost[tomatoe_, lettuce_, spinach_, carrot_, sunflower_, tofu_, chickpea_, oil_] := 1*tomatoe + .75*lettuce +
        .5*spinach + .5*carrot + .45*sunflower + 2.15*tofu + .95*chickpea + 2*oil

energy[tomatoe_, lettuce_, spinach_, carrot_, sunflower_, tofu_, chickpea_, oil_] := 21*tomatoe + 16*lettuce +
        40*spinach + 41*carrot + 585*sunflower + 120*tofu + 164*chickpea + 884*oil

protein[tomatoe_, lettuce_, spinach_, carrot_, sunflower_, tofu_, chickpea_, oil_] := .85*tomatoe + 1.62*lettuce +
        2.86*spinach + 0.93*carrot + 23.4*sunflower + 16.00*tofu + 9.0*chickpea + 0*oil

fat[tomatoe_, lettuce_, spinach_, carrot_, sunflower_, tofu_, chickpea_, oil_] := 0.33*tomatoe + 0.20*lettuce +
        0.39*spinach + 0.24*carrot + 48.7*sunflower + 5*tofu + 2.6*chickpea + 100.00*oil

carbs[tomatoe_, lettuce_, spinach_, carrot_, sunflower_, tofu_, chickpea_, oil_] := 4.64*tomatoe + 2.37*lettuce +
        3.63*spinach + 9.58*carrot + 15.00*sunflower + 3.00*tofu + 27.0*chickpea + 0*oil

sodium[tomatoe_, lettuce_, spinach_, carrot_, sunflower_, tofu_, chickpea_, oil_] := 9.00*tomatoe + 28.00*lettuce +
        65.00*spinach + 69.00*carrot + 3.80*sunflower + 120.00*tofu + 78.00*chickpea + 0*oil

data = Minimize[{energy[tomatoe,lettuce,spinach,carrot,sunflower,tofu,chickpea,oil],
        tomatoe >= 0
        && lettuce >= 0
        && spinach >= 0
        && carrot >= 0
        && sunflower >= 0
        && tofu >= 0
        && chickpea >= 0
        && oil >= 0
        && protein[tomatoe,lettuce,spinach,carrot,sunflower,tofu,chickpea,oil] >= 15
        && 2 <= fat[tomatoe,lettuce,spinach,carrot,sunflower,tofu,chickpea,oil] <= 8
        && sodium[tomatoe,lettuce,spinach,carrot,sunflower,tofu,chickpea,oil] <= 200
        && carbs[tomatoe,lettuce,spinach,carrot,sunflower,tofu,chickpea,oil] >= 4
        && ((lettuce + spinach)/(tomatoe+lettuce+spinach+carrot+sunflower+tofu+chickpea+oil)) >= .40
        },
        {tomatoe,lettuce,spinach,carrot,sunflower,tofu,chickpea,oil}
]

Print[cost[data["tomato"], data["lettuce"], data["spinach"], data["carrot"], data["sunflower"], data["tofu"], data["chickpea"], data["oil"]]]

Export["out.csv", data, "csv"]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The first time I read the expression "the optimal salad" in the question, I thought you were using some obscure jargon, or you had a weird typo :-) That's a fun problem.

Comment: @MarcoB: I edited the question so it's more clear... I see why you were confused at first. :P

Comment: I would think "The Optimal Salad" could be a rock and roll band. Or possibly the name of some super-villain in a Spiderman movie.

Comment: Aww, `the optimal salad` (said in an ominous voice) was great! Too bad, you edited it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following instead of your print statement:

```
Print[cost[tomatoe, lettuce, spinach, carrot, sunflower, tofu, chickpea, oil] /. data[[2]] ]

(* Out: 2.32728 *)
```

The Minimize function returns the following data structure:

> {114.754, {tomatoe -> 1.72651*10^-8, lettuce -> 0.58548, spinach -> 3.53893*10^-8, carrot -> 8.48321*10^-9, sunflower -> 9.69807*10^-10, tofu -> 0.87822, chickpea -> 3.3596*10^-9, oil -> 4.43666*10^-10}}

The first value in the list is the value of the function you minimized at the minimum. The second part is a list of the variable values at that minimum, provided as a replacement list. `data[[2]]` extracts that replacement list. With that, `lettuce /. data[[2]]` gives you for instance the value of the `lettuce` variable.

---

By the way, if all you need is to show the value, you don't need `Print`. The expression

```
cost[tomatoe, lettuce, spinach, carrot, sunflower, tofu, chickpea, oil] /. data[[2]]
```

will be evaluated to its value and that value will be returned. You may still need `Print`, however, if you intend to put this code e.g. inside a `Module`, or a function, etc. where it is not the last evaluated expression.

Comment: Thank you.  I've been struggling to figure out how to handle the return value.  I assumed I needed the Print[] function to handle formatting the type or something :-/.

Answer (score 3):

`data` returns:

```
{114.754, {tomatoe -> 1.72651*10^-8, lettuce -> 0.58548, 
           spinach -> 3.53893*10^-8, carrot -> 8.48321*10^-9, 
           sunflower -> 9.69807*10^-10, tofu -> 0.87822,
           chickpea -> 3.3596*10^-9, oil -> 4.43666*10^-10}}
```

Where `114.754` is the minimum total energy with the constraints you have given. And the values (quantities, I guess) of each individual food are listed as *replacement rules*.

In other words, `Minimize` returns the *minimized value*, as well as *a list of rules to actually minimize whatever you were minimizing*. Not a dataset or a function or anything like that. Just *a list of rules*.

You should note that `data` is not a function, but merely the output listed above.

In any case, you want the *replacement rules* without the total energy. The second (last) part of `data`. For example:

```
rules = Last[data];
tomatoe /. rules
(* 1.72651*10^-8 *)

cost[tomatoe, lettuce, spinach, carrot, sunflower, tofu, chickpea, oil] /. rules
(* 2.32728 *)
```

For bedtime reading:
[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users);

[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice).

Comment: They could probably do with some bedtime reading on `LinearProgramming` too. Their minimize takes around 6 seconds on my machine, the corresponding canonical matrix form LP problem should be practically instantaneous.

Comment: Yeah, but teaching *math* as well as *mathematica* is way too much work :)

Comment: Thank you for the bedtime reading, I will certainly go through it.

Comment: @Histograms: I'm sure I'll get there, my course just started LP, so this is my first introduction to it.

Comment: @Jacobm001 I'll write the matrix LP answer just in case you ever want to look back on it

Comment: @Histograms: That would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Histograms Yes, please do, if you have time! It would be quite nice to have multiple approaches to compare and contrast.

Comment: @Jacobm001 done the LP solution. Interestingly my solution gives an ever so slightly smaller value, but that may be because I simplified some minor constraints or everyone else's Minimize is bigger, who knows.

Answer (score 2):

The `LinearProgramming[...]` solution.
Recall the canonical minimization form for linear programming:

\begin{align}
\mathrm{minimize}\  \mathbf{c}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{x} \ \mathrm{subj\  to:\\}
\mathbf{Ax}\ge \mathbf{b} \mathrm{\ and \ } \mathbf{x\ge0}
\end{align}

In the interest of keeping this answer simple and informative, we can throw out the nonlinear constraint on `(lettuce + spinach)/(...rest...) >= 0.4` because it has a very small effect on the answer except to spread tiny quantities like 10^-8 around (this constraint is what made `Minimize` slow).

First we have to get the constraint matrix in its minimization form; whenever a $\le$ constraint appears we multiply the row and constraint by -1. In the case of the $2\le(\dots)\le8$ constraint we can ignore the 8 and just write this as $(\dots)\ge 2$ (we could add another constraint if we wanted but it makes little difference in this case). The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ (referred to as `m` in the `LinearProgramming` documentation), energy $\mathbf{c}$ and constraint vector $\mathbf{b}$ are now:

```
c = {21, 16, 40, 41, 585, 120, 164, 884}; (* energy objective*)
(* constraint matrix A, called m here*)
m = {{0.85, 1.62, 2.86, 0.93, 23.4, 16.0, 9.0, 0}, (*protein*)
     {0.33, 0.2, 0.39, 0.24, 48.7, 5, 2.6, 100}, (*fat*)
    -{9, 28, 65, 69, 3.8, 120, 78, 0}, (*sodium*)
     {4.64, 2.37, 3.63, 9.58, 15, 3, 27, 0}}; (*carbs*)
b = {15, 2, -200, 4}; (* constraint values *)
quantities = LinearProgramming[c, m, b];
bestEnergy = quantities.c;
Print["Cost: ", cost @@ quantities]
(* result 2.32155
  for quantities: 
  0.5747126436781611` lettuce
  0.8793103448275861` tofu *)
```

The result is lower by a tiny amount probably because we chucked out the nonlinear constraint.

Comment: LP was the first thing that came to mind, too. If the nonlinear constraint has to be enforced, the output of `LinearProgramming[]` could then be used in `FindMinimum[]` as a starting point, with the nonlinear constraint already included in the first argument.